# How to increment docker tag automatically?

Tags: git, shell, docker, tags

I am planning to increment docker tag automatically using shell script. Right now i am using Date function to insert %m%d%y%H%M for docker tag. Every time, current month  year and date with Hours and mins are inserting like 03262016091.

But when I see it in Docker hub, it's not looking good and planning to keep the version names as 1.0.0 or with git commit number.

I am using Travis CI for my continuous Integration but not to build docker images. I have shell script to do that using Docker file.

My Requirement is:

I have to increment below version number everytime when I execute my build.

Version=1.0.0

Could you please help me how to do this?

Comment: What do you have in mind for a versioning scheme? For example when incrementing 1.0.9, will it become 1.1.0 or 1.0.10?

Comment: Any way is okay for me.. i mean 1.1.0 or 1.0.10 or 1.0 -1.1 or after 1.99 increment to 2.0.. My only intention is to increment the version number..

Answer (score 26):

You could use the git revision which is unique as well.
Most simple solution from the command line is a nested git-rev command:

```
docker tag <image> <image>:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
```

gives you e.g.

```
<image> = myImage >> myImage:67df348
```

Answer (score 13):

If your repository were named your/project and was tagged with 1.0, then following should rebuild it with tag 1.01:

```
docker build -t your/project:$(docker images | awk '($1 == "your/project") {print $2 += .01; exit}') .
```

Comment: This snippet makes the assumption that the first image appearing for that project will be a number, and not 'latest'.